# Custom Header and Footer lost after them change in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I was using custom header and footer in my Wordpress Website. After changing the theme, these are lost and I'm unable to find them. Is there a way to use those header and footer in new theme as well?